# change status bar color during splash screen in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, statusbar

I already used

```
cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

and in config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#b83500" />
<preference name="SplashNavigationBarBackgroundColor" value="#b83500" />
<platform name="android">
    ...
</platform>
```

it is not work
and in component.ts

```
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#b83500');
```

but it change after splash screen.

so, how can i change status bar color during splash screen.

Comment: Do you need two different colors for the status bar?

Comment: no, only #b83500 but in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the splash screen plugin and install this version of the plugin from

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/goinnn/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git#4.0.0#colors
```

Following this you can then add the preferences in you configx.xml file as you have already mentioned. However, do place them in the android section

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="SplashStatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#b83500" />
    <preference name="SplashNavigationBarBackgroundColor" value="#b83500" />
    ...
</platform>
```

This will solve you issue.

Do keep in mind this will cause issues with the ios version as this is an older version of the plugin itself. It however works perfectly on android.

This will only change color of status bar on splash screen. To keep the color changed you need to keep the following code in your `app.component.ts` file.

```
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#b83500');
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android, add following in `styles.xml` (I'm showing status bar with white background)

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```